# Relative URLs in JSP specification

Tags: jsp, path, relative-path, specifications, relative-url

I have taken below paragraphs from JSP 2.1 specification document. I'm confused and I need some help with this.

> A page relative path is a path that does not start with a slash (/). It is to be interpreted as relative to the current JSP page, or the current JSP file or tag file,
>   depending on where the path is being used.

I'm good till this. Then,

> For an include directive (see Section JSP.1.10.3) where the path is used in a file attribute, the interpretation is relative to the JSP file or tag file. For a jsp:include action (see Section JSP.5.4, `“<jsp:include>”`) where the path is used in a page attribute,
>   the interpretation is relative to the JSP page. In both cases the current page or
>   file is denoted by some path starting with / that is then modified by the new
>   specification to produce a path starting with /.

The above paragraph says that, in both the cases interpretation is relative to JSP page but how come it will start with '/' ? As per the first paragraph page relative paths does not start with slash right ? Is it a typing mistake ? and shd it be like 'in both cases path should be like "../myfile.jsp" ??

> The new path is interpreted through the ServletContext object. See Section JSP.1.10.5 for exact details on this interpretation.

I agree to this point if the path starts with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

The specification is saying the value of "Current Page" will start with '/'.  That is the page that the path is relative to, not the relative path itself.

So if you specify a relative path, it will use the current path, which will always start with '/', to calculate the new path.  The resulting new path will also be a path starting with '/'.

You just use a relative path to describe a new path in terms relative to the current path.